# unable to read the data of a CSV file present in S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access a CSV file present in S3 bucket . Unfortunately nothing seems to work till now. Can anyone please assist me. All I want to do is access data from CSV which in inside S3 bucket and print some of its columns

Below is the code I tried:
'''

```
                      bucket = "bucket name"
                     file_name = "SUBFOLDER1/SUBFOLDER2/.CSV file"
                     obj = s3_resource.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file_name)
                     initial_df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
                     print(initial_df)
```

''''

Error I get is :
    s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using `boto3`:

**Client method**

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
```

Calls on a **client** map one-to-one to AWS API calls. They return a JSON blog that you can access like:

```
for reservation in response['Reservations']:
```

**Resource method**

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
```

This returns Python **objects** that can be used directly like:

```
for object in Bucket('name').objects.all():
```

Now, to answer your question...

You show this line of code:

```
obj = s3_resource.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file_name)
```

The `get_object()` call should be used on a boto3 **client**, but it appears that you are attempting to use it on a boto3 **resource**. So, you can either use a client instead of a resource, or change the call to a resource-style call.

Comment: Rotenstien -Thanks for the explanation.
 What changes should I do in my code. I am bit confused here

Comment: import boto3
    bucket = "bucketname"
    file_name = " 
  
 Subfolder1/subfolder2/XYZ.csv"
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

''''
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file_name)   
for object in bucket('zone08-data-validation').objects.all():
    print(object)
''''

Comment: is the above code looks correct, cause it still doenst work. and sorry for unformatted text. couldnot format it. newbie to stackoverflow

Comment: You are still mixing-in code from resource and client. If you are using `get_object()`, then please look at the data that is returned as the response. See: [`get_object()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object). If you want to use the `bucket.objects.all()` method, then you'll probably want to print `object.key`. **Bottom line:** Read the documentation for each call that is made.

Comment: See also: [difference between client and resource in boto3 | Edureka Community](https://www.edureka.co/community/39618/difference-between-client-and-resource-in-boto3)